# Sobrescrever o icone default do mat-stepper angular material

Tags: angular, material

Estou tentando sobrescreve o icone default do mat-stepper, mas não parece funcionar. Segui a documentação, mas meu icone fica ao lado do meu label, em vez de sobrescrever e ficar no circulo azul.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-wxawqh)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [matStepLabel não está mostrando o icone - Angular Material](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/340865/matsteplabel-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-mostrando-o-icone-angular-material)

Comment: nao é a mesma coisa, aquele eu consegui corrigir. antes nao aparecia o icon, mas agr nao consigo trocar o icon mesmo usando as especificacoes da documentacao. vc leu por acaso as duas issues ou tu só leu o titulo? nao tem nd a ver uma com a outra

Comment: tentando dar unvote no seu comentario

Comment: Suas dúvidas são muito parecidas, se coseguiu resolver aquele problema poste uma resposta lá. Além disso, não deixe apenas o link para o código, poste aqui também. Não fui eu que votei negativo aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ficar no círculo é só colocar dentro do seu `<mat-horizontal-stepper>` assim:

```
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="number">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
```